# String applying a force on pulley

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Why should string apply a force on pulley? (like atwood machine cases) and does that mean the pulley will exert an equal force on string (newton's third law)?

Please explain in detail,if possible explain with a diagram.

Comment: This sounds very homework-y

Comment: no,not at all.i don't have subjective homeworks at all,but this is a doubt i got, upon attempting another numerical from my package.i wanted it to sound like an homework question else my question will be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are talking about a frictionless pulley, in which case the interaction between the pulley and the string can be considered to be the 'normal force', which is commonly discussed in the textbooks.

And yes, the pulley also exerts an equal and an opposite force on the string. It is this force that enables the string to lift loads.

Comment: Thank you for replying sir,but why should it apply that force and why is the direction downwards in case of atwood machine?and how do you explain the magnitude 2T?

Comment: The force is in the direction that supports the rope from the pulley. Also, the magnitude 2T can be explained by the fact that in a massless rope, the tension across all points is constant. You can see for yourself by drawing a free body diagram of a small element in the rope.

Answer (score 1):

The force between a string and a pulley, like other contact forces, can be broken into two components; friction and a normal, (both of which involve action and reaction). In this case the friction is tangential to the pulley and may cause it to rotate. If the pulley is friction-less (at the axle) and mass-less the tension in the string will be the same entering and leaving.  The normal force on the pulley will vary with position, but can be integrated to give a single effective force. It (and the weight of the pulley) will act on the axle of the pulley and its supporting structure.  If the string enters horizontally and leaves vertically, the horizontal component of the normal force on the string will equal the tension in the entering string, and the vertical component will match the tension in the leaving string.

Answer (score 1):

The pulley has to apply force onto the string so as to prevent the string from piercing it, that is, the electrostatic repulsions. Now by Newton's Third Law there is a reaction by the string onto the pulley.